# Sencha Touch - Redirect to another view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am building a Sencha Touch application and struggling with redirecting or changing another view after login. After login i need to take it to Home Page.  But my below ***code in Login Controller's authenticateUser()not working***.

Tried with Ext.Viewport.push(homePanel) , Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(homePanel) also. But nothing works.

**LoginView**

```
Ext.define("Mobile.view.LoginView", {
extend: "Ext.form.FormPanel",
alias: "widget.mylogin",
id: 'loginFormPanel',

config: {


    name: 'loginform',
    frame: true,
    url: 'login/Authenticate',
    title: 'Login',
    items: [

      {
          xtype: 'fieldset',
          itemId: 'LoginFieldset',
          margin: '10 auto 0 auto ',
          title: '',
          items: [

                {
                    //User Name field def
                },

                {
                    //Pwd Field Def
                }
            ]
      },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            id: 'loginButton',           
            text: 'Login',
            action: 'login'
        }

    ]
}

});
```

**Login Controller**

```
Ext.define("Mobile.controller.LoginController", {
extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
views: ['LoginView', 'HomeView'],
models: ['UserModel'],
config: {
    refs: {
        loginForm: "#loginFormPanel"
    },
    control: {
        'button[action=login]': {
            tap: "authenticateUser"
        }
    }
},

authenticateUser: function (button) {
            loginForm.submit({
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (form, result) {
            //THIS IS NOT WORKING
                Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Mobile.view.HomeView'));

            },
            failure: function (form, result) {                   
                console.log('Error');
                Ext.Msg.alert('Check the logic for login and redirect');
            }
        });
       }           
});
```

**Home View**

```
Ext.define('Mobile.view.HomeView', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
id: 'homescreen',
alias: "widget.homepanel",
 config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'card',
        animation: {
            type: 'flip'
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            id: 'Toolbar',
            title: 'My App',
            items: [
                {
                    id: 'settingsBtn',
                    xtype: 'button',
                    iconCls: 'settings',
                    ui: 'plain',
                    iconMask: true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xclass: 'Mobile.view.ActionListView'
        }
    ]
},
});
```

**App.JS**

```
Ext.application({
name: "Mobile",
controllers: ["LoginController", "HomeController"],
views: ['LoginView', 'HomeView', 'ActionListView'],
models: ['UserModel', 'OrganizationModel', 'ActionModel'],
stores: ['OrganizationStore', 'ActionStore'],
launch: function () {

    var loginPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'mylogin'
            }
        ]
    });
    Ext.Viewport.add(loginPanel);
}

});
```

Any one have any idea?
Already referred [Load another view after login with sencha touch 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944351/load-another-view-after-login-with-sencha-touch-2-0) . But there is no answer . Please help

Comment: any error is coming? If yes,please specify.

Comment: No errors showing. I checked with console.log also. It executed with out error. But view is not changing. Cant we simply change view like  Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Mobile.view.HomeView')); ?

Comment: Initially i am adding login view in app.js lauch function using same way. Now i want to replace it with new view also should not allow user to go back to login page once they authenticated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need create a ref for your HomeView:

```
    refs: {
        HomeView: {
            autoCreate: true,
            selector: 'HomeView',
            xtype: 'HomeView'
        },
    }
```

And set this view active:

```
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getHomeView());
```

Comment: Hi it worked for me. However i modified few things based on 'this' keyword scope and the 'refs' based on the code i put in my question. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: I dont like use id propety, i prefer create a ref with a xtype alias, that way you dont have chance to duplicate id's... but is a option...

Answer (score 1):

If you use Sencha Touch 2, you should use Route to redirect to another page. So, it wil be like this:

```
this.redirectTo('home');
```

Then create a controller with has a route "home"

FOr more information about routes. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/controllers-section-4

Answer (score 0):

Try this. may be this work.

```
authenticateUser: function (button) {
        loginForm.submit({
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (form, result) {

         var home= Ext.create('Mobile.view.HomeView');
         Ext.getCmp('loginFormPanel').destroy();
         Ext.Viewport.add(paneltab);

        }
```